# small resolution while installing kali linux

Tags: kali-linux, grub

[image]Not sure what exactly is going wrong. Im trying to install kali linux in graphical mode and this keeps happening before i can start to install it. I can't do anything other than move the blue line up and down but can't read the options.

Comment: It's something to do with the monitor resolution and refresh rate. Unless you're a security professional using Kali for pentesting etc., I really wouldn't recommend installing it for desktop usage, and [neither do the developers](https://www.kali.org/docs/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux/). It's a security toolbox, not a desktop distro. A better option is downloading a [prebuilt VM](https://www.kali.org/get-kali/#kali-virtual-machines). If you want to learn skills relevant to Kali maintenance, Debian or any of its derivatives will teach them as Kali is based on Debian.